# Deteccion color

Tags: python, windows, opencv, color

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Python para la detección de colores. He logrado detectar los colores rojo, negro, amarillo, azul y blanco.

Mi problema surge a la hora de querer detectar dos tipos de blancos distintos (Blanco y Blanco Perla); este último posee como puntos grises o perlados.

No tengo los colores RGB ya que los poseo en dos Placas como indico en la foto.

Adjunto también el código del proyecto actual; las modificaciones que realice para detectar ambos colores no fueron exitosas por lo que deje la primera versión.

¿Alguna recomendación o alguien tiene alguna experiencia al respecto?

[image: Blanco - Blanco Perla]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# capturing video through webcam

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _, img = cap.read()

    # converting frame(img == BGR) to HSV(hue-saturation-value)

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # red color

    red_lower = np.array([136,87,111],np.uint8)
    red_upper = np.array([180,255,255],np.uint8)

    # blue color

    blue_lower = np.array([99,115,150],np.uint8)
    blue_upper = np.array([110,255,255],np.uint8)

    # yellow color

    yellow_lower = np.array([22,60,200],np.uint8)
    yellow_upper = np.array([60,255,255],np.uint8)

    # white color

    white_lower = np.array([0,0,200],np.uint8)
    white_upper = np.array([180,20,255],np.uint8)

    # black color

    black_lower = np.array([0,0,0],np.uint8)
    black_upper = np.array([180,255,30],np.uint8)

    # all color together
red = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)
blue = cv2.inRange(hsv, blue_lower, blue_upper)
yellow = cv2.inRange(hsv, yellow_lower, yellow_upper)
white = cv2.inRange(hsv, white_lower, white_upper)
black = cv2.inRange(hsv, black_lower, black_upper)

# Morphological Transform, Dilation

kernal = np.ones((5, 5), "uint8")

red = cv2.dilate(red, kernal)
res_red = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = red)

blue = cv2.dilate(blue, kernal)
res_blue = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = blue)

yellow = cv2.dilate(yellow, kernal)
res_yellow = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = yellow)

white = cv2.dilate(white, kernal)
res_white = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = white)

black = cv2.dilate(black, kernal)
res_black = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = black)

# Tracking red
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(red, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if(area > 300):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, "ROJO: ", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255))    

# Tracking blue
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blue, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if(area > 300):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, "AZUL: ", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255, 0, 0))
        

# Tracking yellow
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(yellow, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if(area > 300):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, "AMARILLO: ", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0, 255, 0))

# Tracking white
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(white, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if(area > 300):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, "BLANCO: ", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (255, 255, 255))

# Tracking black
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(black, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if(area > 300):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, "NEGRO: ", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 0))

cv2.imshow("Color Tracking", img)
if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    break
```

Comment: No es necesario ni conveniente que incluyas todo el código (dificulta que otros lo estudien y trabajen con él). Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación